# How to show a WPF Window in front of a UWP app in fullscreen mode?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp

I'm looking for a way to make a WPF window stay on top of a fullscreen UWP app. I found numerous mentions of Window.Topmost, but it only works with a windowed app.

For a little bit of context, the idea is to create a virtual keyboard that I could launch from the app (with a brokered runtime component). I do know that there are some keyboard implementations, but they don't do the trick since they basically edit the textboxes themselves (and I need it to be able to also interact with WebViews).

Thanks :)